# I am getting unable to clone git repository fatal: 'https://dev.azure.com SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: git, github, ssl-certificate, git-clone, self-signed-certificate

I am trying to clone git repository where I am getting below error
**'https://dev.azure.com  SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain.**

I have tried below things:-

1. **git config http.sslVerify false**  after trying this command I am able to clone the repository but while running the application it is giving security issues and I am not able to run the application.
2. Also edited config file globally using and kept only username & email **git config --edit --global**
3. Tried **npm config delete proxy** to check if it is proxy issue but still no luck.

could you please help me out as I am not able to clone the repository without doing git config http.sslVerify false ? and is there any way where we can clone without doing git config http.sslVerify false and run the application.

Comment: Can you tell us more about your setup? Is this happening at home or at the office? Are you using VPN and/or any proxy setups?

Comment: Sure. This is happening with this particular repository only which I am trying to clone. No I am not using proxy or vpn

Comment: Is the repo really on dev.azure.com?

Comment: Yes, It is present

Comment: Are you using an antivirus or firewall other than the OS default?  Those can often be sources of connection tampering.  Usually removing them, rebooting, and using the system default can fix that.

Comment: No, I am not using any firewall or antivirus @bk2204.

Comment: @bk2204 got this working by following command!  git config --global http.sslBackend schannel

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me!
Another method for fixing the ssl certificate problem unable to get local issuer certificate error is to reinstall Git and choose the SSL transport backend option during the installation process.

If the unable to get local issuer certificate error occurs inside Visual Studio Code, you need to grant your repository access to the SSL certificates. To do this, git can be reconfigured with the --global flag on your SSL certificate configuration. This will give the Git server accessibility to the required SSL certificate.

To do this, run the following command in the Terminal:

`git config --global http.sslBackend schannel`

Answer (score -3):

use this command to globally disable sslverify  and then try to clone repository

**git config --global http.sslVerify "false"**

Comment: That removes all security for the connection and allows any arbitrary attacker on the network path to read and tamper with the connection.